# Visio Javascript API fails on load. Missing Microsoft.Office.WebExtension

Tags: office-js, visio, spfx

I'm having Issues with the Visio Javascript API in a SharePoint Framework web part. It has been working but now fails. The 'Visio' object does not get created because a reference to Microsoft.Office.WebExtension is missing in the file https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/embedded/1.0/visio-web-embedded.js.

**The error:**
Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined
at c (visio-web-embedded.js:26)

**It refers to Microsoft.Office.WebExtension in this function in visio-web-embedded.js:**

```js
        function c() {
            Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.onReadyInternal().then((function() {
                return i()
            }
            )).then((function() {
                ...
                }()
            }
            ))
        }
```

After some serarching I added a reference to https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js and got access to Microsoft.Office.WebExtension but then another object in visio-web-embedded.js fails.

**Error:**
visio-web-embedded.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'richApiMessageManager' of undefined
at visio-web-embedded.js:26

```js
case 5:
  return X.promisify((function(e) {
    return OSF.DDA.RichApi.richApiMessageManager.addHandlerAsync("richApiMessage", r, e)
  }));
```

How should I use the visio-web-embedded.js correctly? Is there a referece I'm missing.

The pnp sample project React-Visio has the same issue:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-visio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is an update in the Visio Online API. You could check out my sample, it has static inclusion of the Visio embed and looks like it still works:

https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioOnlineSpfxWebPart

The code includes the Visio API like this (in `package.json`):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/office-js": "^1.1.40",
```

And then in `config/config.json`:

```
  "externals": {
    "VisioEmbed": {
      "path": "node_modules/@microsoft/office-js/embedded/visio-web-embedded.debug.js",
      "globalName": "Visio"
    }
  },
```

Please note that this makes a static reference (i.e. the embed code will be packed into your web part, and not referenced from online Microsoft site). Also, it's a different method if you compare it to the sample you mentioned.
Gives you some stability though - you can be sure that the versions of the libraries you are using are compatible with each other.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Today the file https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/embedded/1.0/visio-web-embedded.js is updated and has no reference to Microsoft.Office.WebExtension. So problem gone.